# how to increase phpmyadmin timeout in lamp server?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

How it is possible to increase timeout of PhpMyadmin.

whenever i go for login i got following message

[image]

so what's current way to increase timeout of phpMyadmin In LAMP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do following steps.

> 1. Edit config.inc.php file in your PhpMyAdmin directory.(/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin)
> 2. Add the line below into anywhere of config.inc.php file

$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = '4500';